# Is there a way to automatically generate a class diagram from existing Java code on Netbeans 11.1?

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram, netbeans-11

I've looked in up online and only found the easyUML plugin. However, the latest version is only updated for Netbeans 8.2. Is there any other way for me to automatically generate a class diagram on Netbeans 11.1?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download and use the easyUML plugin for NetBeans 8.2, install it using the "downloaded" tab of the NetBeans 11 plugin manager (mark all of the plugin files, it should install them all for dependencies), and then use it by first creating an additional new UML project in your workspace and then right-clicking on the existing Java project and selecting the easyUML plugin. The result will appear under the new UML project. Good luck.